# OnMapReadyCallback cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm new to Google Maps inside an Android app and I'm trying to test the example that is included in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

I did some research and apparently this was included in the latest Google Play Services package. I really think I have the last one, but I still cannot resolve OnMapReadyCallback. This is how it looks:

[image]
[image]

Does anybody know what I could be missing?

Thanks

Comment: do you know all steps of using GoogleMap in android?

Comment: I'm new to that, but I already have a key and the map shows correctly in my app.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you need to change to Google APIs, go to `properties` -> `Android`.

[image]

So you will solve the problem implementing the class `OnMapReadyCallback` :

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
```

You need to read all the info related to Google Maps Android API V2:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

You need to create and API project and get the API key to work with Maps.

#### UPDATE:

probably you have an older version of the support library, so delete the current and import the last one, you can use the .jar in your project (located in: `sdk\extras\android\support\v7`) or you can import the library project located in:
`sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`.

Comment: Does that mean that only the newest devices will be able to use it? I would  like it to be compatible with as many devices as possible.

Comment: NO all the devices can use it, but OnMapReadyCallback() method was added in the latests versions Google Maps Android API V2

Comment: Unfortunately I still cannot compile after trying what you suggested. Still doesn't recognize it. I added a new screenshot with the error.

Comment: Hi @LEM , i have updated my answer today i have the same problem, the last version of the library has Android 5.0.1 (api 21) as a build target.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. Way back when I had imported the Google Play Services library into my workspace, I must have checked the box to "Copy projects into workspace". Thus, even though I updated the Google Play Services library with the SDK Manager, the library in my workspace was still the old version. Once I deleted the local version and imported the version from my "android-sdks" folder (without copying this time, of course), Eclipse could find the OnMapReadyCallback class.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

to the dependencies in your build.gradle.