# Android Google Map plotting only one marker but not all

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I was having some problem when trying to display multiple markers on google map in Android. Here is what I did in onCreate():

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLocation, 11.0f));
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    convertedGeomList = RetrieveStoreAsyncTask.convertedGeom;
    for (int i = 0; i < convertedGeomList.size(); i++) {
        // Drawing marker on the map
        drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(convertedGeomList.get(i)
                .getStoreX()), Double.parseDouble(convertedGeomList.get(i)
                .getStoreY())));
    }

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(1.36111, 103.79907))
            .title("Pizza Hut Kranji")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(3.60988, 170.99001))
            .title("Pizza Hut Woodlands")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

I hardcoded two markers to check if it plot but unfortunately, it only plotted one. Then, for the drawMarker():

```
private void drawMarker(LatLng point) {
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    markerOptions.position(point);

    // Adding marker on the Google Map
    map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

I not sure why it only plotted one marker despite my JSON returned with multiple lat and lng. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was thinking if it is because the map has not finish loading then I plot the marker straight away and that's the reason?

Comment: May be but if map loading is the issue, then the first marker shouldn't be visible too... In my very old project, I am using the same approach as yours and its working. Try implementing `OnMapReadyCallback` and instead of `getMap()`, call `getMapAsync()`. And any logs about this problem?

Comment: Would you mind to provide me with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Implement `OnMapReadyCallback` in `Activity` or `Fragment` as this will provide you `onMapReady(GoogleMap map)` method.

Now in **onCreate()**:

```
((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
```

And,

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLocation, 11.0f));
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        convertedGeomList = RetrieveStoreAsyncTask.convertedGeom;
        for (int i = 0; i < convertedGeomList.size(); i++) {
        // Drawing marker on the map
            drawMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(convertedGeomList.get(i)
                    .getStoreX()), Double.parseDouble(convertedGeomList.get(i)
                    .getStoreY())));
    }
```

Comment: It tells me OnMapReadyCallback is unable to resolved. I did added google service lib as reference of my project already. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you are using an older version of google maps library. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755174/onmapreadycallback-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) to **fix unable to resolved** error.

Comment: It is still unresolved eventhough I changed it to 5.1.1 in the properties. I can't import it as well. Is there any other way to fix this than adding the getMapAsync?

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#the_maps_activity_java_file). Hope this will help you out.